# Can Immutant be configured to use something other than 8080 as well as to use SSL?

Tags: clojure, immutant

I am playing around with immutant and was wondering how to set two things:

- to setup an alternative ssl port
- to use port 80 instead of port 8080

Comment: I would strongly urge you to consider using a reverse proxy, e.g. apache, haproxy, nginx, or even a hardware load balancer to do the ssl decoding for you. It's a more conventional architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the http port, you have two options - you can edit
`$IMMUTANT_HOME/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` and
change the `<socket-binding name='http' ...` element, or pass
`-Dhttp.port=80` to `lein immutant run` or `standalone.sh`, depending
on how you are starting Immutant.

To alter the https port, your only option currently is to edit the
`<socket-binding name='https' ...` entry in
`$IMMUTANT_HOME/jboss/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml`.